# Difference in nullability of reference types error when building with .NET 5 SDK

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, .net-5, nullable-reference-types

I have implemented the following extension methods on `IDictionary`, which will try to get a value from a dictionary, but return a default value (either `default(T)` or user-provided) if the key doesn't exist. The first method without a user-provided value will call through to the other method with `default`.

```cs
[return: MaybeNull]
public static T GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T>(this IDictionary<TKey, T> source, TKey key) where TKey : notnull
{
    return GetValueOrDefault(source, key, defaultValue: default);
}

[return: MaybeNull]
public static T GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T>(this IDictionary<TKey, T> source, TKey key, [AllowNull] T defaultValue) where TKey : notnull
{
    if (source is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (key is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
    
    if (source.TryGetValue(key, out var item))
    {
        return item;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

With .NET SDK 3.1.100 this code builds fine. However, with the newest .NET SDK 5.0.101, I get the following error message:

> error CS8620: Argument of type 'IDictionary<TKey, T>' cannot be used for parameter 'source' of type 'IDictionary<TKey, T?>' in 'T? DictionaryExtensions.GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T?>(IDictionary<TKey, T?> source, TKey key, T? defaultValue)' due to differences in the nullability of reference types.

It complains about the use of `default` in `GetValueOrDefault(source, key, defaultValue: default)`. Using `default!` suppresses the error message of course, but the value is supposed to be nullable (hence the `AllowNullAttribute` on `defaultValue`). Or maybe it is deducing that `T` is nullable due to the attribute and usage, and won't allow a call with the non-nullable `T`?

The error is only produced when `T` is generic and not constrained to `class`. For instance, the following code does not produce the error:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.GetValueOrDefault("key", null);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Has the constraints on nullable reference types been further tightened with the new .NET version? Is this simply a bug with .NET SDK 5.0.101?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I think the nullability analysis just improved.

`[AllowNull]` and friends don't affect the compiler's inference of generic type parameters. What seems to be happening here is that the compiler is looking at the call to `GetValueOrDefault(source, key, defaultValue: default)` and trying to infer what `TKey` and `T` are. Because you're passing `default` as a value of `T` (ignoring `[AllowNull]`), it realises that the `T` given to `GetValueOrDefault` has to be nullable, i.e. it's invoking `GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T?>(source, key, defaultValue: default)`.

However, it's also realised that `source` could be an `IDictionary<TKey, T>` (so that `T` isn't nullable), and realised that there's a clash here.

This is all academic, as C# 9 [introduced the `T?` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations). This is significantly neater than adding attributes, supports things like `Task<T?>`, and is better integrated with the compiler.

This works as you'd expect:

```
public static T? GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T>(this IDictionary<TKey, T> source, TKey key) where TKey : notnull
{
    return GetValueOrDefault(source, key, defaultValue: default);
}

public static T? GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T>(this IDictionary<TKey, T> source, TKey key, T? defaultValue) where TKey : notnull
{
    if (source is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (key is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));

    if (source.TryGetValue(key, out var item))
    {
        return item;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Here the compiler still notices that you're passing `default`, but it realises that `defaultValue` has a type `T?` rather than `T` (where it was ignoring the `[AllowNull]` attribute before), and so doesn't force `T` to be nullable.

---

If you're stuck with C# 8, it seems that explicitly specifying the generic type parameters stops the compiler from inferring the `T` as a `T?`, which gets rid of the warning:

```
return GetValueOrDefault<TKey, T>(source, key, defaultValue: default);
```

Comment: "This is all academic, as C# 9 introduced the T? syntax. This is significantly neater than adding attributes, supports things like Task<T?>, and is better integrated with the compiler." - 

That's awesome, and not something I have seen highlighted at all. As a matter of fact, I can't seem to find anything about it even when looking for it. Do you have a resource detailing this change?

Comment: I was looking for one to link to and failed: I can't find any official documentation on it whatsoever. There's [this mention in an LDM meeting](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/a3d67d141501101af9dbb9e8192ca8b4c717e316/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-03-27.md#nullable-reference-types): I've seen other sources in that repo, including issues/discussions, but I can't locate them right now

Comment: However I did find [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-07-27.md#w-warnings-for-t-t--default), which looks like it might be related to your issue (although it isn't an exact fit)

Comment: "you can only get rid of the warning in C# 9, so at a minimum it should only be reported in C# 9" - interestingly, I am using C# 8 in this project, so if I am reading this correctly I shouldn't get this warning.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's probably a related issue, but not exactly what you're seeing: I suspect your case is simply the nullability analysis improving

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Another question is then: Is this possible at all with .NET 5 SDK and C# 8 (without falling back on the `!` workaround)?

Comment: I did find a way: edited onto the bottom of my answer

Comment: Aha, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations) is a good resource